# JC Higgins girls bike. Trying to identify year of manufacture

Tags: vintage

I have a JC Higgins girls bike (flightliner ??) with the serial number 502 45390 185598 that I'm trying to identify the model year. Any help?

Comment: I don't see any reliable information on JC Higgins by serial number. There is no central database. Serial number lookup information for bicycles is compiled by fans of the bike and are based on their best guess based on available data. There is a tiny chance that if you give us good pictures we can find a matching picture in a catalog somewhere.

Comment: Serial numbers are surprisingly unhelpful in identifying bikes. You'll likely have better luck if you post a few photos of the bike from different angles.

Comment: Why do you want to identify the model year? if it is about value, check completed ebay auctions
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=JC+Higgins+Flightliner+&_sacat=0&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1